# How to handle Creation & Modified Date in .NET MVC Entity Framework Migration?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, linq, entity-framework, date

How can I use Entity Framework and Migration to add a CreationDate and ModifiedDate to some (not all) of my Model-classes to automatically update the Database, and also automatically update the Database for these fields with the current DateTime?

To make it more clear, this is what I'd like to add using Migration to two of my Database-tables:

```
CreationDate   DATETIME    DEFAULT NULL,
ModifiedDate   TIMESTAMP   ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

I've added them in the Model like this:

```
public DateTime? CreationDate { get; set; }
public int ModifiedDate { get; set; }
```

My only idea I had so far is: Override the `DbContext#SaveChanges()` to something like:

```
public void SaveChanged()
{
    // Somehow check if the Tables in the Data I want to update contains a ModifiedDate
    // or Data I want to create contains a CreationDate
    // And add them with the current DateTime if these fields are present in the table(s)

    base.SaveChanges();
}
```

I don't even know if this above is possible and how I can access the LINQ-query I want to use on the Database, but if this is the right direction, what should I put at the comment-lines? And if this isn't the correct way of handling this, how should I do this then?

**TL;DR: How to use Entity Framework Migration on a Model(-Field) so it uses `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`?**

Comment: Not quite clear, you are looking for migration or you done for data migration and now looking for how to do CRUD on data?

Comment: @AshishRajput I'm looking to do automatic Migration using .NET mvc Entity Framework to alter two of my tables so it adds a CreationDate and ModifiedDate field and I also want to fill these CreationDate and ModifiedDate in these two DB-tables automatically with the current DateTime right before or when I call `MyDB.SaveChanges()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you enable automatic migrations, the model will be updated when your application instances the `DbContext` for the first time in your application. That usually happens the first time the application uses the `DbContext` for some CRUD operatiosn, but it can also be triggered by calling the `DbContext.Database.Initialize` method. But you don't need to do it!!

To understand how to enable automatic migrations, and how they work, read thoroughfully this document: [Automatic Code First Migrations on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj554735.aspx). You can easyly navigate from this docuemnt to other related ones to improve your understanding of EF.

The attributes in your class are correct, but you don't need to specify those related to the `DateTime` property: EF conventions will make a DateTime property the desired type on the DB side (a nullable DATETIME in this case).

*NOTE: a timestamp has nothing to do with a date, it's an incrementing number to mark the "version" of the row, i.e. it changes whenever the row is updated, but it's not a date but a number*

Comment: I just asked around at my company to some people with a bit more experience in EF Migration, so I now know a bit more of how it works. Still thanks for the answer and link. But my main concern is how to use Migration so the CreationDate is automatically filled whenever I add an item to one of those two database-tables and how the ModifiedDate is automatically updated whenever I update an item in one of those two database-tables. Maybe I should rephrase my question a bit: "How to add a ModifiedDate with `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` to a database-table using Entity Framework?"

Comment: If you feel you should change your question, then go, change it, explain what you need. You won't get the answer you want with the wrong question. I think I've answered your question...

Comment: Though I don't mind the answer of how to use Migration with EF in general, since I'm also kinda new to that, I did ask about how to handle Creation & Modified Dates with EF Migration specifically. That part of my question isn't answered yet. Perhaps it's now more clear what I want to accomplish with the edited question..

Comment: To make it clear Migrations can only be used to update the DB conforming to the Code First model changes. Not more than that. So, you have made a question that cannot be answered. I've explained what you can do with migrations. If you need to do the other thing, that has nothing to do with migrations, and should be asked in a whole new, completely different question. Please, don't spoil your time, an create that new question.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but the only answer doesn't even come close to answering the right question!

Here's how to do it:

Just loop the ChangeTracker collection in the DbContext like this:

```
public virtual int SaveChanges()
{
    foreach (var item in this.ChangeTracker.Entries())
    {
        var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
        var modelBase = item.Entity as IModelBase;
        if (modelBase != null)
        {
            switch (item.State)
            {
                case EntityState.Added:
                    modelBase.CreatedOn = now;
                    goto case EntityState.Modified;

                case EntityState.Modified:
                    modelBase.LastModifiedOn = now;
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

You also need an interface and preferably a base class like below:

```
/// <summary>New interface classes should implement if they already have a base class.</summary>
/// 
public interface IModelBase
{
    [Key]
    string Id { get; set; }

    DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    DateTime LastModifiedOn { get; set; }

    string CreatedById { get; set; }
    string LastModifiedById { get; set; }
}
/// <summary>Base class model classes should inherit if they do not have an existing base class. Any MVC framework classes with existing base classes should implement the interface instead.</summary>
/// 
public class ModelBase:IModelBase
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastModifiedOn { get; set; }

    public string CreatedById { get; set; }
    public string LastModifiedById { get; set; }
}
```

Then finally your model classes either need to inherit the base class or implement the interface:

```
public class MyTrackedClass : ModelBase
{
     // Your code here!
}
```

Or

```
public class MyTrackedClass : IModelBase
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastModifiedOn { get; set; }

    public string CreatedById { get; set; }
    public string LastModifiedById { get; set; }
     // Your code here!
}
```